# Create pod with helm chart and second config file

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I want to create a helm chart which has 2 configuration files. I tried to add second config file which will be read as a yml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: vault-second-configuration
data:
  vault-configuration.yml: |
    mockup-internal-configuration:
      value: test
```

Full source code and configurations:

https://github.com/rcbandit111/mockup/tree/master/helm_chart/mockup-chart

I start the pod using:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "mockup.jar", "--spring.config.additional-location=file:/home/config/application-mockup-configuration.yml", "-Dvault.local.config=/storage/vault-configuration.yml"]
```

When I use the same command locally as VM options it's working fine.

But every time when I try start the pod the configuration file `/storage/vault-configuration.yml` it's not found. Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: How are you attaching that ConfigMap data to your Pod?

Comment: I added a code example. Please review the github project into the post.

Comment: You don't seem to have included it directly in the question.  Can you [edit] the question to directly include it?  Just the ConfigMap isn't quite enough detail, seeing the volume mounts in the Deployment spec is important.

Comment: Please see the github link into the post. The files are quire a lot to include them here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your [`rcbandit111/mockup` helm_chart/mockup-chart/templates/deployment.yaml](https://github.com/rcbandit111/mockup/blob/master/helm_chart/mockup-chart/templates/deployment.yaml), you already have  [`volumeMounts` section](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#background) and volumes set up for your ConfigMaps. You have a `vault-configuration` volume that maps to a [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/) of the same name and mounts it to `/storage/vault-configuration.yml`.

```yaml
...
containers:
  - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
    ...
    volumeMounts:
      ...
      - name: vault-configuration
        mountPath: /storage/vault-configuration.yml
        subPath: vault-configuration.yml
    ...
volumes:
  ...
  - name: vault-configuration
    configMap:
      name: vault-configuration
...
```

Your [`vault-configuration.yml`](https://github.com/rcbandit111/mockup/blob/master/helm_chart/mockup-chart/templates/vault-configuration.yml) is:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: vault-configuration
data:
  sec-configuration.yml: |
    test:
      second-line: value
```

That shows a mismatch between the filename in the ConfigMap and the filename expected in your `deployment.yaml`.

The `data` section of your `vault-configuration` ConfigMap defines a file named `sec-configuration.yml`, but in your `deployment.yaml`, you are trying to mount a file named `vault-configuration.yml`.

Either update the `vault-configuration` ConfigMap to use `vault-configuration.yml` as the key.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: vault-configuration
data:
  vault-configuration.yml: |
    test:
      second-line: value
```

Or modify the `deployment.yaml` to mount `sec-configuration.yml` instead of `vault-configuration.yml`.

```yaml
volumeMounts:
  - name: vault-configuration
    mountPath: /storage/sec-configuration.yml
    subPath: sec-configuration.yml
```

The key is to make sure consistency between the filename in the ConfigMap and the filename referenced in the `deployment.yaml`.